# Template Doesnot Exist at in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to render a template inside a function. Below is my settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['E:\Django\googlemaps\templates\waypoints'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

and views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
   'Display map'
    return render_to_response('waypoints\index.html')
```

And below is my error when i run the server.Please help me.

```
    http://dpaste.com/0SZAR4H
```

Comment: Is this your complete error? Your url seems invalid unless you have deliberately declared that url `waypoints\index.html` should be `waypoints/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

The template you are trying to access is according to the path:

```
waypoints\index.html
```

I think it should rather be

```
waypoints/index.html
```

Comment: are you on windows? what is your django version?

Comment: Yes am in windows and am using django 1.8.3. And also I made a folder named templates in my project and new folder inside templates waypoints and then "index.html".

Comment: This is basically a path error. The template path you are specifying is not matching your directory path. Rather than hard coding your directory structure, try this: `TEMPALTE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")]`. Here `BASE_DIR` is the variable as in your default settings file and `templates` is the directory where your template resides.

Comment: It will recurse over all the directories and files inside that path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85111/discussion-between-arpit-goyal-and-harinish).

Comment: Your templates dir includes waypoints.  So maybe you are pointing to: E:\Django\googlemaps\templates\waypoints\waypoints\index.html?  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `\t` in `\templates` is being treated as a tab character.

The easiest fix is to **always use forward slashes**. This works, even on Windows.

```
'DIRS': ['E:/Django/googlemaps/templates/waypoints'],
```

Your other options are:

- use two backslashes, i.e. `\\t`
- use the `r''` prefix i.e. `r'E:\Django\googlemaps\templates\waypoints'`.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced settings.py shown above by

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "templates"),
```

)
It worked fine.

But i would like to know what makes the difference.